# Cargar módulos al retroceder una pagina en Angular6

Tags: html, html5, angular, typescript

El problema es el siguiente, tengo unos cuantos routerlinks y algunos modulo en la vista principal llamada, para efectos de simplicidad: equiz(x), todo va bien, todos me cargan a las rutas que deben de ir y todas las vistas de los modulos linkeados se muestran como es debido, sin embargo, cuando preciono F5, recargar la pagina, o ir hacia adelante o hacia atras, no cargan los modulos como es debido, simplemente recarga a la pag principal y algunos modulos quedan en la vista... aca un peq extracto del codigo:

```html
<!-- ACA TERMINA EL HEADER DEL SIDEBAR-->
            <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL CONTENIDO DEL SIDEBAR -->
                
            <ul  class="list-unstyled components ">
                    <p>{{gestion}}</p>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" *ngIf="cero">Herramientas</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a routerLink="/crear" *ngIf="uno" (click)="titulo1() " >Crear</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a routerLink="/modificar" *ngIf="dos" (click)="titulo2()">Modificar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="tres">Eliminar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="cuatro">Ejecutar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a routerLink="cdp" *ngIf="cinco" (click)="cambiartitulo()">Crear Caso de Prueba</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="seis">Estado</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="siete" (click)="cambiartitulo1()">Modificar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="ocho"(click)="cambiartitulo2()" >Copiar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" *ngIf="nueve">Eliminar</a>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                  
            <!-- ACA TERMINA EL CONTENIDO DEL SIDEBAR -->
        </nav>
        <!-- ACA TERMINA EL SIDEBAR -->

<div id="content">
    <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL NAVBAR -->
    
    <a *ngIf="diez"> <app-barrasearch></app-barrasearch></a>
    <a *ngIf="once"><app-barraproyecto></app-barraproyecto></a>
    <a *ngIf="doce"><app-barrasola></app-barrasola></a>
```

Este seria una porcion del .TS

```html
titulo2():void{
  this.gestion = "Gestion de Casos de Prueba";
  this.uno = false;
  this.dos = false;
  this.tres = false;
  this.diez = false;
  this.cuatro = true;
  this.cinco = true;
  this.seis = true;
  this.siete = true;
  this.ocho = true;
  this.nueve = true;
  this.once = true;
  
}
```

Entonces, si preciono por ejemplo modificar, el direcciona a la vista de modificacion, carga el modulo de router link y tambien activa un componente en este caso barra proyecto, que pasa, si llegase a devolverme o a recargar las vista que se deberian  de mostrar no son las correctas, todo se desfasa/desordena y no se muestra como deseo... puesto que se activan unas vistas y se desactivan otras... espero poder darme a entender D: help

Comment: Yo mismo me respondi esto, me doy like a mi mismo, para el q vea o lea esto y tenga la misma duda... lo resolví utilizando routers hijos, de esa manera en el url siempre se mostraran todos los path que deseo observar !!

Comment: Si pudiste encontrar la respuesta, redacta una respuesta como es debida... Las personas que tengan tu mismo problema buscaran la respuesta en el apartado de respuestas, y no en los comentarios.

Comment: Yo mismo me respondi esto, me doy like a mi mismo, para el q vea o lea esto y tenga la misma duda... lo resolví utilizando routers hijos, de esa manera en el url siempre se mostraran todos los path que deseo observar !!